# How to get the primary key(id) of the next entity to be created in DbContext c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

Is it possible to get the value of the primary key of the entity to be created next? Before it is created?

I tried:

```
Order newOrder = new Order();
MessageBox.Show(newOrder.orderId.toString());
```

It showed 0.

Is it possible?

**Bigger Picture:**

I am trying to build a fast food order management system. I have `Order`, `Item` and `OrderItem` tables. There is a many-to-many relationship between `Order` and `Item` and `OrderItem` table resolves this relationship.

So, when adding an order, I need to add `OrderItem` s whose `orderId` field should be populated by the 'Order' just being created, i.e. is not created yet.

**EDIT:** I use Code-First approach.

Comment: If it's database assigned, then no, you cannot know what the id will be until it has been inserted.  For your particular problem I don't see a need for knowing the id, you should just have relationships between the models and let EF handle the mapping between the two.

Answer (score 2):

EF will take care of it.

So if you have Code First, you could do something like:

```
class Order
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set }

   public virtual List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }

   public Order()
   {
     Items = new List<OrderItem>();
   }
}

class OrderItem
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string ItemName { get; set; } //of course just a demo property
}
```

and do something like:

```
Order order = new Order()

OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
item.ItemName = "Super Burger";

order.Items.Add( item );

context.Orders.Add( order );
context.SaveChanges();
```

All is well and the keys populated accordingly.

Comment: sure - but by this point EF will have created the record in the database. The OP asked if `orderID` could be retrieved BEFORE it was created

Comment: I was taking his 'bigger picture' into account - and given my approach, knowing the Id is - usually - no longer necessary.

Answer (score -1):

If the key is generated at the database then no, it's not possible. So I see 2 alternatives:

1. You can just add the entity to your collection, then call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` to write it to the database and use the id value in your code. (You could do this inside a transaction and rollback the transaction subsequently, or even just remove the record, if needs be.)
2. You can generate the id value yourself in your code rather than having something generated by the database - perhaps by using a GUID as an ID

There are positives and negatives to each approach depending on how this fits into whatever your 'big picture' is.

UPDATE:

in terms of positives and negatives - the first option is probably closer to what you originally planned. And can be made to work. Arguably would make it easier to set up relationships with other entites. On the flipside you need to hit the database each time you want to get a new id - which could be slower.

It's really a (opinion based!) design decision - either method can be made to work.

Comment: I think you will find that option 1 with rollback won't work.

Comment: Acknowledging I should have suggested doing it inside a transaction when suggesting roll-back. Think my answer was still reasonable though. Have edited to clarify now

Comment: @Stewart_R, I tried to explain the bigger picture in my question. Please, see my update

Comment: Even inside a transaction it will not work. If you add the id 5, then roll it back, the next one to be added will still be 6. Try it.

Comment: @DavidG yeah, of course. But he can still use the value 5 in his code to determine if it needs to be rolled back. Nothing wrong with having a new id next time per se?

Comment: @Jahongir it's really your call - I've added a brief update to give you some initial things to think about